# Windows 8 recimg createimage fails with 0x80070002, why?

Tags: windows-8

Running Win8 x64. C is an SSD with lots of free space (>200GB). I run:

```
recimg /createimage C:\CustomRefreshImages\Img121105
```

Output says:

```
Source OS location:  C:
Recovery image path: C:\CustomRefreshImages\Img121105\CustomRefresh.wim
Creating recovery image. Press [ESC] to cancel.
Initializing

The recovery image cannot be written.
Error Code - 0x80070002
```

The paths specified in the command line are created, and I'm running this in an elevated command prompt, so it's not a permissions issue.

I've googled this but could only find worthless results, including a particularly entertaining one where the "solution" included instructions for creating a screenshot (press PrtScreen). Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: 70002 usually means it cannot find the file specified, just guessing it could be a user profile issue.

Comment: That may be: My user profile is on D, but there's a symlink to C (because C is an SSD). Could that be the problem? It works fine in practice.

Comment: Its a guess [based on this page](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2008/03/12/common-causes-and-solutions-to-backup-system-restore-and-complete-pc-backup-problems-updated.aspx) that has the same error for File Backup in Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have TrueCrypt installed?

I too had this problem and found a blog post (http://blog.itbubble.ru/2012/11/recovery-image-creator-recimgexe-fails.html) which mentioned that an active mount at the root directory could cause a similar error.

I checked my C:\ and found no mount point there, but *Mountvol* did give “The system cannot find the file specified” under a number of volume names, which might be what was causing VSS to fail during *Recimg* initialization.

In my case, the invalid volume names were created by TrueCrypt.  (If you mount a TC volume and then unmount it, you’ll see the volume name left there; and this, according to http://insertwittylinkhere.blogspot.com/2012/05/wmi-query-failed-provider-failure.html, is an old bug.)  After I uninstalled TrueCrypt, I was able to create recovery images again.

Please let me know if this solved your problem.

Comment: Victory!!! That was _it_! Problem solved, thank you so much!

Comment: By the way, if you do need TrueCrypt, you can install it in portable mode, so that TrueCrypt-created volume names are cleared with a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

```
error Code - 0x80070002 recimg -createimage
```

Run Windows Update from Control Panel and restart the system, then run the following command:

```
recimg -CreateImage drive?:\foldername?
```

Comment: So just to make sure I'm tracking with your second line: The argument can be something like `d:\backup` ?

Answer (score 1):

I found that unmounting any open truecrypt volumes and rebooting worked not only with the portable version but also when you're using the truecrypt installer. In other words, it's not necessary to uninstall truecrypt, just reboot to clear the mount points.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310214157/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/979281) to the same situation for Windows 7 and i think it will work for Windows 8 also. This is a Knowledge Base of Microsoft from actual scenario.

This article is also useful
for [Windows 8](https://web.archive.org/web/20151130045722/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/01/04/refresh-and-reset-your-pc.aspx)

Just Check if it helps

also try **recimg/help** to do checklist of commands available

AS per the details the Link summarizes that it can be due to two reasons

> After you back up files by using Windows Backup on a Windows 7-based computer, you receive a notification that resembles the following:Check your backup results
> The backup completed but some files were skipped.

> When you click the Options button that is next to the notification, you receive the following message:Check your backup results
> The backup completed but some files were skipped.
> View skipped files

Now from that they have given 3 scenarios and their  causes and the Resolution,as the Steps are long i referred to the page as it is a KB

The next link suggests ways to Refresh your PC and why it should be done

It Suggests

> Reset your PC – Remove all personal data, apps, and settings from the PC, and reinstall Windows.
> Refresh your PC – Keep all personal data, Metro style apps, and important settings from the PC, and reinstall Windows.

Comment: How about summarizing what the linked pages say?

Comment: I'm afraid this information doesn't really help resolve my error. :\ Thanks for trying, all the same.